# Direct EventHandler roots

Tags: c#, .net, events, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

Currently i try to find some memory leaks in our software, because after a while it crashs with a `OutOfMemory` exception. At first i want to proof, whether there is no event which causes the memory not to be freed. When i use `.Net Memory Profiler` for profiling, after a while using our application i get the result: `16 types have instances that are directly rooted by an EventHandle`. To find the reason for this, i've taken a look at the created diagram:

[image: profiling result]

Complete overview:
[image: Overview]

Finding reasons for this behaviour using the diagram is not very easy at the first time. Are there some tricks/hints i am missing? I know, finding some "memory leaks" is not an easy task, but it has to be done. So should i use the diagram in general or is there some other way too? maybe some one has some information how to analyze the behaviour by using .net profiler.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Download Red Gate Memory profiler which has a 14 day fully functional free trial. You should be able to find the root cause of the leak with just a single run

Comment: Yep, ANTS seems to be easier to use. The most advantage is, they have good wiki articles to get to know what a result/diagram mean. Thank you!

Comment: Believe me, once you start that tool, wou will not need any wiki to achieve what you want. I am a big fan.

Comment: Yes, seems to be very comfortable.

Comment: Ok, only if it is intresting for some one. One problem seems to be old legacy code, which contains static events. Oh oh

Comment: Interesting to me! most of the leaks I had to deal with turned out static event handlers, and almost always, listening to these events were member methods of Page instances (asp.net pages), which caused the whole page, HttpContext and everything to be kept in memory for good.

Comment: Good to know i am not the only one with this problem. Thank you for sharing your experience!

Comment: :) Good luck with the leak :)